# Libreoffice Draw Export Resolution makes no sense

Tags: libreoffice

I am attempting to make a very simple label using Libreoffice Draw v 4.0.2.2.  The label has not much more to it than regularly spaced lines of centered text

This image will be printed, and I have a fixed size/ppi requirement to ensure appropriate print quality.

I set the page size to my specs, and layout the text as I desire.  The print shop takes several image formats including .tiff and .png.  When I export the image, a dialog pops up that asks for the image size/ resolution.  The given ppi is very low (~40) and I require a minimum of 180ppi.  When I enter this, the image size adjusts itself and results in an image that is far too small.

The only solution that appears to be viable is to explode the page size and the drawing text size so it gets shrunk upon export.  This is a very imprecise and illogical feature (bug?) of the program that I really wish is a result of my ignorance.

I found a [thread](http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/Re-libreoffice-users-Creating-High-Res-Images-in-Draw-or-Impress-td4002136.html) in the mailing list which describes this issue exactly.  The only answer that is given is essentially "yes, this is ridiculous and doesn't help anybody".

Can anyone give some advice to this?  Or at least shed some light on who might need this "feature"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something off about the Export tool of LibreOffice in general. It has been years since it is broken. Taking a screenshot is an alternative, but obviously you cannot control the resolution.

So, a better work around is exporting to SVG, and then convert the SVG to PNG with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). Once downloaded, convert the file with the following command:

```
inkscape -z -e out.png -w 1024 in.svg
```

If you are in Windows (x64), you will need to indicate the full path:

```
"C:/Program Files/Inkscape/inkscape.exe" -z -e out.png -w 1024 in.svg
```

If you install the 32 bit version, this should work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)/Inkscape/inkscape.exe" -z -e out.png -w 1024 in.svg
```

Comment: This is a good tip, vector images scale trivially.   It is, however, tedious that an extra step must be added to the workflow because of an apparent lack of enthusiasm from the project developers.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done from inside Libre Office, there is no need to use any external tool. The Export dialog is very confusing, yes; you have to realize that both *size* **and** *resolution* can be set independently.

Select *File* -> *Export* -> choose the desired format. The export dialog should appear.

**TAKE NOTE** of Width and Height. Set the desired resolution; notice how Width and Height change (?). Don't worry, **restore** Width and Height to your saved values. And that's it. You get a high resolution image with the desired size and DPI.

Comment: Thanks, it works even though the implementation is very strange. After setting back the width and height to their original values, one needs to check the radio box resolution again.

Answer (score -2):

Libre Draw (the one I'm using anyway) is a vector drawing app - have you asked the print shop if they can use vector formats like eps, pdf? Most should be able to in my experience.  Then resolution becomes irrelevant.

-Terry