# Circle not round any more after export in Libre Office Draw

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

If you draw a circle in Libre Office Draw, you get a perfect circle. However, if you export it with "File -> Export..." and export it as a "Selection" and save it as a .png or .gif picture the right and bottom part of the circle are not round any more. See the picture below.

[image: irregular Libre Office Draw circle]

What can be done about this? Is there a work-around available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) worked for me.  Export as vector SVG from LibreOffice, then open in Inkscape and export as raster PNG file.  Here is my circle:

[image]

The recommendation is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726722/5100564.  I used the Inkscape GUI rather than the command line commands suggested in the answer.